# Grav import blueprints

Tags: grav

I have a question about blueprints import and need some help.

i have a partial blueprint (.yaml) file that contains:

```
form:
   .import_works:
      label: imported Label
      type: text
      default: import default
```

If i import this file into a list as follow:

```
header.works:
   type: list
   fields:
   import@:
      type: partials/mypartial
```

it works like expected.

But if i import it to bind directly to a *header.* variable it doesnt work:

```
header.not_working:
   import@:
      type: partials/mypartial

header.not_working_2:
   fields:
   import@:
      type: partials/mypartial
```

can someone help me, please.

Thanks in advance!